# Iframe Embedded servlet is making the doGet() method getting called twice

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a servlet called **mainSvlt** . Now when I hit my url address, the `doget()` method gets called and it provides response through the view `main.jsp`. In `main.jsp`, I have included a fragment jsp called `frag.jsp`, which contains an iframe. Now the url of the iframe is like : `src=".\khgSvlt"` .The problem is if i include the iframe url in the src, the `doget()` of **mainSvlt** gets called again, i.e. it gets called twice, which leads to errors in my page.

**1> Why is this happening ?**

**2> How can I mitigate this problem ?**

Any suggestions will be appreciated .

Comment: do you resize the iframe after load ?

Comment: @KennethClark : No I don't ,it contains media css , which gives responsive sizing .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the problem was the servlet  call in my iframe src, due to which the `doGet()` of the main servlet gets called again . So what i did was : Got rid of the src attribute from the iframe tag and am appending the src tag, only when that the fragment jsp is getting called after the `DOM` has loaded. This way the main `servlet doGet()` gets called only once .

Answer (score 0):

The browser retrieves the IFRAME content as a separate resource -- eg, a separate request to your server. That request should be handled by the appropriate servlet mapped for that URL.

If the specified URL is mapped to the same servlet, that servlet will get invoked twice -- which isn't necessarily a problem, but having a distinct servlet for separate responsibilities may be cleaner design perspective.

Servlets are allowed to be concurrently invoked & should be stateless to allow this; they should have no request- or conversation-specific members.

Then it's a matter of the servlet being coded appropriately for the content it is intended to deliver -- the templating & boilerplate are typically different,  eg the IFRAME does not typically include a page header or banner etc.